# Unable to Log into Samsung Account on Samsung S5 Neo

Tags: hardware

Entered correct email and password. Next step.

Entered correct 2-step Verification code. On pressing next, refreshes page and asks for code again. Never actually logs in.

Restart Phone ... NO FIX

Reset Password ... NO FIX

Answer (score 0):

Went on my desktop and logged into samsung accounts from there, 2-step verification worked on their wekapp login portal. Then went into security settings (webapp), disabled 2-step verification, restarted the phone.

Then was able to log into Samsung Account successfully (phone).